# ActionView::Template::Error (TinyTds::Error: adaptive server connection timed out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7, tiny-tds

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5Sqy.png)

above error getting on production.
it's working on staging env.

in database.yml given below configuration

```
 pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
 timeout: 4000000
```

also for each loop i have used

```
(2..spreadsheet.last_row).each_slice(500) do | batch |
  batch.each do | i |
   # remaining code here
  end
 end
```

but after using above still getting same error on production env.